# Which browsers allow intercepting of HTTP 401 requests within extensions?

Tags: browser, http-authentication

I am looking to implement a custom authentication mechanism for HTTP server that is serving up requests to local users and I would like to write a browser extension to handle the challenge - I am considering the challenge being in the form of a HTTP 401 response with a custom mechanism name specified in a WWW-Authenticate header.

Of the common browsers currently in use, which if any of these can you intercept and respond to a HTTP 401 response from within an extension without the browser handling the 401 automatically?

If intercepting the HTTP 401 is not possible then I have some alternative ideas regarding how to implement what I am trying to achieve it is just to begin with I would prefer to explore the 401 approach so that it can co-exist with the other HTTP authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why existing mechanisms wont do the job? it seems a bit not-invented-here

Comment: The reason for considering using a WWW-Authenticate header is to allow it to co-exist with the existing mechanisms available not to replace them.